# jQuery Masonry and UI Sortable

Tags: user-interface, grid, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-masonry

There's this website I'm developing which can be found [here](http://www.feathers.pt). It's a photography website and my client asked for me to implement something that would allow her to move the photos around and change the order of which they appear. They come from a MySQL database and are displayed with jQuery Masonry.

I thought instantly of jQuery UI Sortable, and I've been trying to implement it with absolutely no luck at all. 
How can I achieve this? Can someone point me in the right direction, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't just post links to your site. You should put the relevant code in your question. Plus you need to demonstrate knowledge of the question being asked... what issue are you having with jQuery UI sortable?

Comment: Well, I can't sort out the elements, only move them around. The code is this script here: http://www.mrclay.org/2013/06/05/simpler-masonry-sortable-working-together/
But I also need to be able to order them in the database and I have no ideia how :/

I apologise for the lack of knowledge...

Comment: You might want to look at packery http://packery.metafizzy.co.  It's basically masonry with sortable built in.

Comment: I agree with @watson. The website to which you refer doesn't exist anymore, so where this issue could have helped me, I'm now still in the dark.

Answer (score 3):

I am struggling with the same issue, so far my answer has been to change classes with jquery's sortable start, stop, change and sort events. Like so:

```
$('#sortable').sortable({    
        start:  function(event, ui) {            
                 console.log(ui); 
            ui.item.removeClass('masonry');
            ui.item.parent().masonry('reloadItems')
                },
        change: function(event, ui) {
            ui.item.parent().masonry('reloadItems');
                },
        stop:   function(event, ui) { 
            ui.item.addClass('masonry');
            ui.item.parent().masonry('reloadItems');
});
```

Here is a [working example](http://tyler-designs.com/masonry-ui/)  and a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/desandro/XMfwZ/1/) on the subject. It's a start.

However, this is not a 'presto' solution, this examples work with older versions of masonry, the latest version has a few bugs implementing it since the "reload" method was replaced with layout() and reloadItems(). 
Or... you can use the old masonry versions, if it works for you.

Alternatively you can use [jQuery.Shapeshift()](http://mcpants.github.io/jquery.shapeshift/), which does basically what you're looking for.

Comment: This was not enough for me. I had to add "$container.masonry()", or "msnry.layout()" in my case, after the "reloadItems" call to refresh the view.

Comment: Same for me as what Sander said. ui.item.parent().masonry('reloadItems'); By itself does nothing for me.