# How do i get jQuery Sortable working with jQuery Masonry?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-masonry, jquery-ui-sortable

I have both [jQuery Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) and [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/events.html) working. When i combine the two sortable doesn't want to work correctly.

As i drag an item the other items do not move however the backend (Rails) does work because is saves the position when i refresh the page even though it didn't show that it moved. So the front end is the problem.

If i drag object 1 to the last position none of the other objects will move on the screen it is like they are stuck in place. I am pretty sure i need to do something so Masonry is refreshing as i drag the object.

Here is my code in Coffeescript

```
jQuery -> 
    $('.listwrap').sortable
     update: ->
       $.post($(this).data('update-list'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))

$(document).ready ->
  $('#container').masonry
    itemSelector: '.list'
    columnWidth: 200
return
```

I have tried these but i can't seem to get it to work.

[jQuery Masonry conflict with jQuery UI Sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141082/jquery-masonry-conflict-with-jquery-ui-sortable)

[jQuery Masonry and UI Sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324405/jquery-masonry-and-ui-sortable)

Comment: You could use masonry creator's other library [packery, which includes  draggable functions](http://packery.metafizzy.co/draggable.html).

Comment: Packery supports jQuery Draggable but not jQuery Sortable. I need something for jQuery Sortable.

Answer (score 0):

using following code in update does the trick:

```
grid.masonry('reloadItems');
grid.masonry('layout');
```

where grid is a masonry jquery object.